# Distribute compilation on a server that itself distributes on more computers

Tags: distcc

If I distcc my compilation on a unique server, is it possible to this server to distribute its compilation to many more computers by using distcc too?

Another way to ask it: is the distcc distribution stopped after one distribution or is it recursive?

In the case it would be recursive, does it handle cycles smoothly? (Computer A distributing on computer B that distributes on computer A.)

I am discovering distcc, and I want to know if I can design a compilation sub-network accessible only through a bastion without any knowledge on the computers in this sub-network.

Answer (score 0):

I think distcc stops you from calling distcc on a client machine. This is so that you can set up a pool of build machines for a team, work on any one of them and have them all build together.

Comment: Did it check out OK?